# How do I make my html file responsive again?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

SO, I was trying to create my portfolio. I added an extra button to download resume and the whole thing became unresponsive and it's unresponsive even after I delete the resume button. I don't know where the problem is. I tried changing most of the parameters.

```css
.nav-pills{
  
  font-size: 2.2em;
  background-color:black;
  margin-bottom: 16%;
}
body{
 background-color: none;
 font-family: Lobster;
 color: white;
    position: relative;

}
.pageone{
 background: url("https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1419242902214-272b3f66ee7a");
 background-size: cover;
 height: 700px;
 border-top: 4%;

}
.container-fluid{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;


 }
h1{
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top:0px;
 font-size: 6em;
}
.btn-default{
 background: black;
 border-color: black;
 color: #337aa9;
 font-size: 1.4em;

}
.boxone{
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.8;
 width: 50%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto
}

.pagetwo{
 background: url("https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465101046530-73398c7f28ca");
 background-size: cover;
 height: 680px;
 
 padding-top: 5%
}
p{
 font-size: 2.0em;
}
.dp{
 padding: 16%;
 border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<Head>
<title>Puneeth</title>
</Head>

<div class="pageone text-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li><a href="#">Puneeth S</a></li>
<li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="boxone ">
<h1>Puneeth S</h1>
<h3>Engineer by chance, Developer by choice</h3>
</div>
<div class="btn-list text-center">
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Resume</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Facebook</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Twitter</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Linkedin</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Github</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="pagetwo">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<img src="https://s20.postimg.org/uguojmpvx/abcd.jpg" alt="trial" class="dp">


</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<h1 class="text-center">Puneeth S</h1>
<p class="text-center">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `.row` class in `.container` in `.pagetwo` block:

```
<div class="pagetwo">
  <!-- `.container` element eliminates negative horizontal margins from `.row` -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/uguojmpvx/abcd.jpg" alt="trial" class="dp">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">Puneeth S</h1>
        <p class="text-center">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked...:D
If you don't mind, Can you explain the logic. I'm not able to figure out why that worked.

Comment: Because, `.row` element adds negative horizontal margins to inner elements. This is because you're having horizontal scrollbar, when wrapping elements in `.row`. To eliminate these negative margins, you should wrap `.row` elements in `.container`.